# Where is HTML5 changelog?

Tags: html, standards, changelog

[HTML5 is Living Standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) and a lot of devs even think that it is an umbrella of specs for JS/DOM/CSS/SVG/MathML/etc.

Are there any historical reference / changelog for HTML5 (as umbrella)? More precisely I look for date/time log about spec status/version/fixes changes.

**PS** Question is not about http://caniuse.com/ but about standard committees activity ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually 2 HTML specs, the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) and the [WHATWG living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/). Much like the browsers themselves, while differences in the specs may be a little confusing, multiple specs help push the web forward. Both are used as references for browser implementations.

I don't know about history on the W3C spec but WHATWG hosts theirs on [GitHub](https://github.com/whatwg/html) so you can look at the [commit history](https://github.com/whatwg/html/commits/master).

Comment: That I afraid of - digging into commit history instead looking to  user  noticeable changes ((

Comment: Yeah I don't think there is really any other way to track the changes outside of blog posts/articles from the community. You can normally rest assured that specs don't change much once they've been implemented by browsers though.

Comment: "multiple specs help push the web forward"... Umm, multiple *disjunct* specs. with clearly different focus, like 1 HTML + 1 CSS = multiple specs., then sure... The immense confusion caused by this unprecedented case of two parallel, overlapping, competing *and conflicting* HTML quasi-standard specs. caused a lot of harm. Thankfully, the specs war is over, and there are no longer two subtly different HTML specs to "help push the web forward"... :)